# Change the text <Select a value> and (Select All) in SSRS into some other text

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas

I have parameters that have the (select a value) and (select all) options.
I need these to be translated in my language, so I want to change the text.
Can someone show me where can I change the text?

Thanks in advance,
Olga

Comment: First you need to answer to yourself, Where does reports is hosted, at SSRS or in other app etc WinForms or WebForms throught reportviewer.

Comment: it's hosted at ssrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the language of the web browser to your preference and the SSRS prompts will be automatically translated.
For IE go to Internet Options > Languages > Set language preference then add the desired language and move it up, to set it as default.

Comment: Is there another way because I use Chrome and the option for my language is grayed out?

Comment: You may need to add the language to Chrome first